# SSH connection not working when connecting from specific IP

Tags: networking, ssh, 18.04, password

This issue has actually been occurring for me for awhile now, however, it didn't "bother" me enough, but is now becoming somewhat of a frustration.

I upgraded to 18.04 in May, and since the upgrade I've been unable to connect to the host from an external IP, which I used to be able to. When trying to connect, the connection is instantly closed. I can see the connection in `auth.log` is successful, but then instantly afterwards a disconnect is logged.

At first, I assumed that perhaps the upgrade had changed the firewall settings. A quick `sudo ufw status numbered` threw that out the ball park, as rule 5 showed:

```
[ 5] 22                         ALLOW IN    12.12.12.1
```

(IP address anonymised for obvious reasons). There are no `DENY` rules prior to rule 5.

Ok, so I thought, maybe `sshd_config` had been altered, and had disallowed Password authenication. So I checked that, however, I confirmed that the entry is still there:

```
Match Address 12.12.12.1
    PasswordAuthentication yes
```

So, I thought, let's try a different IP address. So, temporary, I added my Phone providers IP range to `sshd_config` to allow Password Authentication (I normally use a private key, so the IP address range is already in ufw), by adding the following:

```
Match Address 82.132.*.*
    PasswordAuthentication yes
```

I then restarted sshd (`sudo service sshd restart`) and tried to connect. Success! Ok, so it's not that Password Authentication is being flat out blocked.

So, next thought, it's the firewall at the location when I tried to connect. Well, I have a 16.04 container on the host as well, so I added a entry on my router to forward a different port to the container's SSH port (22). Added the external IP to ufw, and added `PasswordAuthenication yes` to `sshd_config`. When I tried to connect, the connection was successful. So, it's not the firewall at the external location either; as I can connect to a 16.04 host fine.

This, therefore, really has me stumped. I can't see why I can't connect, using password authentication, to the host. I admit, I haven't tried setting up a further 18.04 container and trying to connect to that. I'm more than happy to try, however, if people think it's relevant. I, also, haven't tried setting up a key at the external location, however, I am specifically trying to use Password Authentication here (yes, I'm aware it is not as secure).

To confirm though, the question is, why am I unable to connect via SSH, using password Authentication, from this specific IP, and how can I fix it? Why is it that it works fine from another IP when both have the relevant entries in `sshd_config` and ufw? Why would the connection suddenly stop working after I upgraded to 18.04 (it worked fine when using 16.04), and it seems that connecting to 16.04 still works, as I can connect to a container (on the 18.04 host) without a problem from the IP I'm having a problem with.

It's probably worth noting, as well, that I don't have problems connecting to other ports on the same host from the specific external IP. For example, I am able to connect apache without a problem, and I also set up the transmission daemon and was about to connect to the web service hosted by that.

My full sshd config (with IP anonymised):

```
#   $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.101 2017/03/14 07:19:07 djm Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

PubkeyAuthentication yes

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
#AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server

Match Address 12.12.12.1
    PasswordAuthentication yes

Match Address 192.168.1.*
    PasswordAuthentication yes
```

For reference, my UFW output:

```
:~sudo ufw status numbered
Status: active

     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 8081                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 2] 22                         ALLOW IN    1.2.3.0/17           
[ 3] 10022                      ALLOW IN    4.5.6.0/30             
[ 4] 22                         ALLOW IN    4.5.6.0/30             
[ 5] 22                         ALLOW IN    12.12.12.1                
[ 6] 22                         ALLOW IN    192.168.1.64/26           
[ 7] 22                         DENY IN     Anywhere                  
[ 8] Samba                      DENY IN     192.168.1.254             
[ 9] Samba                      ALLOW IN    192.168.1.0/24            
[10] Plex                       ALLOW IN    192.168.1.0/24            
[11] 8081 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[12] 22 (v6)                    DENY IN     Anywhere (v6)
```

And an extract from `auth.log` of when I tried to connect today from the IP:

```
Jun 19 10:08:23 ihy sshd[15066]: Connection reset by 12.12.12.1 port 59644 [preauth]
Jun 19 10:08:45 ihy sshd[15086]: Connection reset by 12.12.12.1 port 30982 [preauth]
```

As you can see, the connections are getting to the host, but instantly resetting.

*Edit: when using `ssh -vvv` from one of the Linux hosts (I normally use Putty on a windows host) at the external address the result is:*

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /usr/local/etc/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "{Domain}" port 10022
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to {Domain} [{IPAddress] port 10022.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/{username}/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/{username}/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/{username}/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/{username}/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/{username}/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/{username}/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/{username}/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/{username}/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

*And the output from `iptables -L`:*

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-reject-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-track-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-reject-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-track-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-reject-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-track-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-ns
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-dgm
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:netbios-ssn
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:microsoft-ds
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST
Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "
Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp destination-unreachable
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp source-quench
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp time-exceeded
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp parameter-problem
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
ufw-user-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ufw-logging-deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp destination-unreachable
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp source-quench
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp time-exceeded
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp parameter-problem
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:bootps dpt:bootpc
ufw-not-local  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             224.0.0.251          udp dpt:mdns
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             239.255.255.250      udp dpt:1900
ufw-user-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW AUDIT] "
Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW AUDIT] "
Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW AUDIT] "
Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ufw-user-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "
Chain ufw-logging-deny (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW AUDIT INVALID] "
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
Chain ufw-not-local (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type MULTICAST
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST
ufw-logging-deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-input (7 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW
Chain ufw-user-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:32400
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:32400
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:tproxy
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:8081
ACCEPT     tcp  --  1.2.3.0/17      anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     udp  --  1.2.3.0/17      anywhere             udp dpt:22
ACCEPT     tcp  --  no-dns-yet-12.12.12.0.zen.net.uk/30  anywhere             tcp dpt:10022
ACCEPT     udp  --  no-dns-yet-12.12.12.0.zen.net.uk/30  anywhere             udp dpt:10022
ACCEPT     tcp  --  no-dns-yet-12.12.12.0.zen.net.uk/30  anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     udp  --  no-dns-yet-12.12.12.0.zen.net.uk/30  anywhere             udp dpt:22
ACCEPT     tcp  --  no-dns-yet-12.12.12.1.zen.net.uk  anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     udp  --  no-dns-yet-12.12.12.1.zen.net.uk  anywhere             udp dpt:22
ACCEPT     tcp  --  no-dns-yet-12.12.12.1.zen.net.uk  anywhere             tcp dpt:10022
ACCEPT     udp  --  no-dns-yet-12.12.12.1.zen.net.uk  anywhere             udp dpt:10022
ACCEPT     tcp  --  ihy.home/26          anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     udp  --  ihy.home/26          anywhere             udp dpt:22
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:22
DROP       udp  --  BThomehub.home       anywhere             multiport dports netbios-ns,netbios-dgm /* 'dapp_Samba' */
DROP       tcp  --  api.home             anywhere             multiport dports netbios-ssn,microsoft-ds /* 'dapp_Samba' */
ACCEPT     udp  --  192.168.1.0/24       anywhere             multiport dports netbios-ns,netbios-dgm /* 'dapp_Samba' */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.1.0/24       anywhere             multiport dports netbios-ssn,microsoft-ds /* 'dapp_Samba' */
ACCEPT     udp  --  192.168.1.0/24       anywhere             multiport dports 1900,mdns,32410,32412,32413,32414 /* 'dapp_Plex' */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.1.0/24       anywhere             multiport dports 32400,32469 /* 'dapp_Plex' */
Chain ufw-user-limit (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
Chain ufw-user-limit-accept (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
Chain ufw-user-logging-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
Chain ufw-user-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: What does iptables -L say on the instance you can't login on with your desired IP?

Comment: `Connection reset by 12.12.12.1` suggests it's the client side that's bailing, maybe? have you tried running SSH in verbose mode e.g. `ssh -vvv 12.12.12.1` ? Some reference here: [Meaning of “Connection closed by xxx \[preauth\]” in sshd logs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102502/meaning-of-connection-closed-by-xxx-preauth-in-sshd-logs)

Comment: @steeldriver added the output for you

Comment: @jeroen won't be able to obtain that till later, as I'll need to be at the host. Will let you know when it's available.

Comment: @jeroen updated for you. Had to remove the output from the container for `ssh -vvv` to fit it in, mind.

Comment: More than 4 years later do you still have the same problem? Have you upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: I'm running 20.04 now a days, @user68186 . I have not upgraded to 22.04 as yet, as not everything I use has been updated for 22.04 as yet. As for the problem, I think I switched to certificates in the end; but that was (like you said) 4 years ago.

Comment: Do you mean public-private keys when you say certificates? Did it solve the problem?

Comment: I honestly couldn't tell you if I ever managed to fix password authentication 4 years ago, @user68186 . I don't have the same set up anymore,